# Integration of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^8+1}} $

Tags: calculus, integration

How can we integrate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^8+1}}$ thanks for help.

I couldn't find any way. I tried to factor, substituted with $\tan(a)$ but it's not working :'(

Comment: Have you tried subbing $x = \tan^4(u)$?

Comment: no, can you write it down if it's powerful ?

Comment: WolframAlpha gives an expression that involves hypergeometric functions, so presumably there is no closed-form solution.

Comment: @Travis. There are closed forms which involve elliptic integrals.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That depends on one's definition of "closed". To me (and probably a typical student asking this question) this excludes elliptic functions, but of course, this definition is arbitrary.

Comment: @Travis. I totally agree with you ! However, using elliptic integrals is better than hypergeometric functions (I think). Cheers :-)

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for more information. Also, letting $t=\dfrac1{1+x^8}$ , we can express the integral in terms of the $($ [incomplete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) $)$ [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Answer (score 7):

Given $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^8+1}}dx\;,$ Now Let $x^4 = t\;,$ Then $\displaystyle 4x^3dx = dt\Rightarrow dx = \frac{1}{4x^3}dt = \frac{1}{4}t^{-\frac{3}{4}}dt$

So Integral Convert into $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{4}\int t^{-\frac{3}{4}}\cdot \left(1+t^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}dt$$

Now Using Integrals of differential binomials and Chebyshev’s criterion

> Integration of $$\displaystyle \int x^{m}\cdot (a+bx^n)^{p}dx$$ in terms of elementry function is Possible only, When
>
> $$\displaystyle p\;,\frac{m+1}{n}\;,\frac{m+1}{n}+p$$ is an Integer, Where $m,n,p\in \mathbb{Q}$.

So above we have $\displaystyle m=-\frac{3}{4}\notin \mathbb{Z}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{m+1}{n} = \frac{\left(-\frac{3}{4}+1\right)}{2} = \frac{1}{8}\notin  \mathbb{Z}$ and

$\displaystyle \frac{m+1}{n}+p = \frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{2} = -\frac{3}{8}\notin  \mathbb{Z}$

So We can Not express the Integral $$\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^8+1}}dx$$ in terms of  Elementry function..

Comment: WOW I learn [something new](http://www2.onu.edu/~m-caragiu.1/bonus_files/CHEBYSHE.pdf) today! Thank you!